# Rails iteration math operator causes a wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This iteration prints the highest index value.

It works and prints 8 eight times.

```
- @videos.each_with_index do |video, index|   
  = index.size
```

---

When I add a math operator it doesn't work and gives me this error: **wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)**

```
- @videos.each_with_index do |video, index|   
  = index.size - 1
```

Comment: If this question is marked down, please at least give a reason.

Comment: This is in a HAML template?

What happens when you do `= (index.size) - 1`?

Comment: Oh thanks, it is a HAML template and your answer worked. Please repost your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Out of interest, does `index.size() - 1` work also?

Comment: Yes, index.size()-1 works.

Comment: What do you expect `index.size` to represent?

Comment: I expected it to represent the complete length of the sum of all stored elements in the Videos table. And I see it working the way I expected.

Comment: @Cadence96 Try it on a collection of videos with cardinality other than eight elements. `index.size` will still produce `8`. What does "complete length of the sum of all stored elements" mean? How do you sum videos? Do `video` objects respond to `:+`?

Comment: The 8 number changes when I add or delete content. The size() is the way I get the sum of the quantity of videos. What do you mean with your last question?

Comment: According to the code you have posted, your are calling size on `index`, which is the second parameter yielded from `each_with_index`.  The size of index is the byte size of a fixnum and has nothing to do with the number of videos in your collection.

Comment: The last question is because the words you use do not match the code you wrote, or any obvious interpretation. @videos is a collection, you can find the size(or length) of that collection but it makes no no sense to have the "length of the sum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like:

```
index.size - 1
```

is being interpreted as:

```
index.size(-1)
```

Try adding in parenthesis to force it to be interpreted in the correct way:

```
(index.size) - 1
```

or:

```
index.size() - 1
```

Comment: Well, adding the parens might fix the exception in the haml context, but this answer doesn't address the root of the problem. `index.size` is the byte size of a Fixnum, almost certainly not what the OP was thinking it is.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I failed to see that. Have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`index` in your example is a Fixnum, the index of the element in the enumeration.  [`Fixnum#size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-size) returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of a Fixnum. Probably not what you were looking for. It accepts zero arguments which explains the exception you got.

The fact that `index.size` returns `8` is because you're running on a 64bit architecture and has nothing to do with the size of `@videos`.